# gulp iconfont: Failed to decode downloaded font, OTS parsing error: head: Bad ppm of 13

Tags: css, wordpress, gulp, icon-fonts

The icon displays in Safari but not FF or Chrome.

Getting the following errors on local development:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://client.dev/wp-content/themes/client/build/assets/fonts/icons/client.woff2
(index):1 OTS parsing error: head: Bad ppm of 13
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://client.dev/wp-content/themes/client/build/assets/fonts/icons/client.woff
(index):1 OTS parsing error: head: Bad ppm of 13
```

Any idea why? Can I somehow validate the generated font files? Thanks!